# Count the number of occurence of a case sensitive word in a paragraph in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to count the number of occurrence of a specific words in a paragraph.

I am writing my code for key down event. I may have few hundreds words initially that may increase later on.

SO when the user is typing i will match the words in a paragraph and then get the number of occurrence. I also need to make sure that the match will be case sensitive.

Right now i am using this code:

```
$('.msg').val().split("AP").length - 1
```

Where AP is the keyword to match.

But i am not very happy with this.

**Actually i have a list of few hundred keywords, how can i implement it efficiently.**

Please note the words to match have spaces on both side i.e they are boundary words

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does the paragraph start prepopulated, or is it all user input? Can the user cut/paste text in?

Comment: @mrtsherman It is a textbox so user can type as well as cut copy etc

Comment: So you want to keep a running tally of the keywords as they are typed into the textbox?  I.e., if someone types "to be or not to be", then after typing the first "to", then dict["to"] gets the value 1, and then after he types the second "to" it gets the value 2 (assuming "to" is in your dictionary).  Is that the idea?

Comment: @BobS  yes, you are right i want to implement the same

Comment: And if your dictionary has "foo" and "bar", you want to know the number of "foo" separately from the number of "bar"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

```
var wordList = ["some", "word", "or", "other", "CASE", "Sensitive", "is", "required"],
    wordCount = [];

for (var i=0; i < wordList.length; i++)
   wordCount[i] = 0;

$("#someField").keyup(function(){
   var i,
       text = this.value,
       re;
   for (i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
      re = new RegExp("\\b" + wordList[i] + "\\b", "g");
      wordCount[i] = 0;
      while (re.test(text)) wordCount[i]++;
   }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zMdYg/2/ (updated with longer word list)

I don't really know what you want to do with the results, so I've just stuck them in a simple array, but you can see in the demo I then output them to the page so you can see it working. Obviously you'd substitute your own requirement in that part.

This is using a regex to test each word. You'll notice that with `.split()` or `.indexOf()` you'll get partial matches, e.g., if you look for "other" it will also match partway through "bother" (and so forth), but with the regex I've used `\b` to test on word boundaries.

For a large list of words you might want to create all the regexes in advance rather than redoing them on the fly in the loop, but it seemed to work fine for my simple test so I thought I wouldn't start doing premature optimisations. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 1):

If split() is not case-sensitive, then I would look at using indexOf(), which is case sensitive.

So maybe something like:

```
var words_array = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var carot = 0;
var n_occurences = 0;

$.each(words_array, function(index, value){

  while(carot < $('.msg').val().length && carot > -1){

    carot = $('.msg').val().indexOf(' ' + words_array[index] + ' ', carot);

    if (carot > -1){

      n_occurences++;
    }
  }
});
```

I haven't tested this but I hope you get the idea.